# Python pandas equivalent to R's group_by, mutate, and ifelse

Tags: python, r, pandas

Probably a duplicate, but I have spent too much time on this now googling without any luck. Assume I have a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"letters": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
        "boolean": [True, True, True, True, True, False],
        "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to 1) group by letters, 2) take the mean of numbers if all values in boolean have the same value. In R I would write:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(letters) %>%
  mutate(
    condition = n_distinct(boolean) == 1,
    numbers = ifelse(condition, mean(numbers), numbers)
  ) %>% 
  select(-condition)
```

This would result in the following output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   letters [2]
  letters boolean numbers
  <chr>   <lgl>     <dbl>
1 a       TRUE          2
2 a       TRUE          2
3 a       TRUE          2
4 b       TRUE          1
5 b       TRUE          2
6 b       FALSE         3
```

How would you do it using Python pandas?

Comment: SO is not meant to be a code translation service. Besides your research, what have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

We can use lazy `groupby` and `transform`:

```
g = df.groupby('letters')

df.loc[g['boolean'].transform('all'), 'numbers'] = g['numbers'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
  letters  boolean  numbers
0       a     True        2
1       a     True        2
2       a     True        2
3       b     True        1
4       b     True        2
5       b    False        3
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be to use np.where. where a group has one unique value, find mean. Where it doesnt keep the numbers. Code below

```
df['numbers'] =np.where(df.groupby('letters')['boolean'].transform('nunique')==1,df.groupby('letters')['numbers'].transform('mean'), df['numbers'])



letters  boolean  numbers
0       a     True      2.0
1       a     True      2.0
2       a     True      2.0
3       b     True      1.0
4       b     True      2.0
5       b    False      3.0
```

Alternatively, mask where condition does not apply as you compute the mean.

```
m=df.groupby('letters')['boolean'].transform('nunique')==1

df.loc[m, 'numbers']=df[m].groupby('letters')['numbers'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: `transform('all')` can be reused here; I feel nunique might be tricky, especially if all the booleans are False

Answer (score 5):

Since you are comparing drectly to R, I would prefer to use `siuba` rather than `pandas`:

```
from siuba import mutate, if_else, _, select, group_by, ungroup

df1 = df >>\
    group_by(_.letters) >> \
    mutate( condition = _.boolean.unique().size == 1, 
            numbers = if_else(_.condition, _.numbers.mean(), _.numbers)
          ) >>\
    ungroup() >> select(-_.condition)

print(df1)
letters  boolean  numbers
0       a     True      2.0
1       a     True      2.0
2       a     True      2.0
3       b     True      1.0
4       b     True      2.0
5       b    False      3.0
```

Note that `>>` is the pipe. I added `\` in order to jump to the next line. Also note that to refer to the variables you use `_.variable`

## EDIT

It seems your R code has an issue, In R, you should rather use `condition = all(boolean)` instead of the code you have. That will translate to `condition = boolean.all()` in Python

Answer (score 0):

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) is another solution for you:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {"letters": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
...         "boolean": [True, True, True, True, True, False],
...         "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>>
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, mutation, n_distinct, if_else, mean, select
>>> df >> group_by(f.letters) \
...    >> mutate(
...         condition=n_distinct(f.boolean) == 1, 
...         numbers = if_else(f.condition, mean(f.numbers), f.numbers)
...       ) \
...    >> select(~f.condition)
   letters  boolean   numbers
  <object>   <bool> <float64>
0        a     True       2.0
1        a     True       2.0
2        a     True       2.0
3        b     True       1.0
4        b     True       2.0
5        b    False       3.0

[Groups: letters (n=2)]
```